# How can I import a specific type block?

Tags: 8, blocks

I have created some blocks of a specific type, in Drupal 8, and I want to import them into the cloned instance.

There is no core import feature available. How can I achieve the task?

They don't get imported by the configuration synchronization; if you try, you will get the error

> This block is broken or missing. You may be missing content or you might need to enable the original module.

and no listing in custom block library.

Answer (score 0):

As per my further research I found that there is a module named **[Content Synchronization](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_sync)** which works well with the same issue. As in Drupal 8 blocks as served as content now and block types as entity types.